# Needing to move values of one column based on values of another matching column names in a separate data frame

Tags: r

I have two data frames, `split` and `nsD`. Inside of `nsD`, I have two columns: one containing numeric data (`nsD$counts`) and other containing an 8-character ID tag (`nsD$ID`).

| counts | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | hb123400 |
| 31 | hb123400 |
| 22 | hb123400 |
| 48 | aa339800 |
| 13 | aa339800 |
| 9 | aa339800 |

Inside of `split`, each column name corresponds to the values in `nsD$ID`.

| hb123400 | aa399800 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |

What I need to do is move the values of `nsD$counts` for which `nsD$ID` matches the individual column names in `split`, and I need to be able to do this for all 551 columns/IDs easily. I'm honestly unsure of how to get there; I know for-loop containing `which()` is likely involved, but I'm unsure of how to proceed. (If it helps, I also have a chr list `IDlist` containing the unique IDs.)

Desired outcome:

| hb123400 | aa399800 |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 48 |
| 31 | 13 |
| 22 | 9 |

Thanks for any help!

ETA: I have successfully moved a small portion of this data using the following code:

`nsD$counts[which(nsD$ID=="2982b018")] -> split$2982b018`

This moves one small (1881 values, out of 1mil+) portion of data to the right column, but as you can see, I'm having to individually designate which ID tag to look for.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

We don't need to create an empty datasets of 0s and fill it.  Suppose, we want only some 'ID' elements from 'nsD', `filter` those (here it is based on the column names of 'split', but it can be just a `vector` of names), then we use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr` to reshape from 'long' to 'wide'.  As there are duplicate elements, make sure that we create a sequence id to make it unique (`rowid` from `data.table` - or use `group_by(ID) %>% mutate(rn = row_number())` in dplyr)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
out <- nsD %>%
    filter(ID %in% names(split)) %>%
    mutate(rn = rowid(ID)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = counts) %>%
    select(-rn)
```

-output

```
out
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  hb123400 aa339800
     <int>    <int>
1       12       48
2       31       13
3       22        9
```

---

Note that when we are not loading packages correctly, there can be side-effects i.e. `filter` is one function which is present in `base R` `stats`.  So, if we didn't load the `dplyr` with `library(dplyr)`, this can be result in `filter` being used from the `stats` package

```
 nsD %>%
+     stats::filter(ID %in% names(split)) %>%
+     mutate(rn = rowid(ID)) %>% 
+     pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = counts) %>%
+     select(-rn)
Error in ID %in% names(split) : object 'ID' not found
```

Generally, with `tidyverse` packages, there are some function names that are  also present in other packages i.e. `summarise/mutate` can get masked with `plyr::summarise/plyr::mutate`.  A better practise is to either use `::` or create a unique name by assignment

```
nsD %>%
     dplyr::filter(ID %in% names(split)) %>%
     dplyr::mutate(rn = rowid(ID)) %>% 
     tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = counts) %>%
     dplyr::select(-rn)
```

Or may use

```
filter_d <- dplyr::filter
mutate_d <- dplyr::mutate
select_d <- dplyr::select
nsD %>%
     filter_d(ID %in% names(split)) %>%
     mutate_d(rn = rowid(ID)) %>% 
     tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = counts) %>%
     select_d(-rn)
```

#### data

```
nsD <- structure(list(counts = c(12L, 31L, 22L, 48L, 13L, 9L), ID = c("hb123400", 
"hb123400", "hb123400", "aa339800", "aa339800", "aa339800")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

split <- structure(list(hb123400 = c(0L, 0L), aa339800 = c(0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

NOTE: `split` is a function name.  It is better not to name objects with already existing functions.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work.
'Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
ℹ Input `..1` is `ID %in% names(split)`.
x object 'ID' not found'

Comment: @EmilyRobbs Based on the edit on your comment.  I think `ID` is not the column name.  But, you showed the data having two columns and its names as `counts` and `ID`.  Can you show the `colnames(nsD)`

Comment: @EmilyRobbs Yes, you can just assign the output to a new object namei.e. `out <- nsD %>%...`

Comment: @EmilyRobbs I think you haven't loaded the package.  please see the update.  You may have used `stats::filter` instead of `dplyr::filter` because once you load the package with `library(dplyr)` filter from stats will be masked by dplyr::filter

Comment: Ah, this finally worked. I did not mention that I had a third column in nsD that actually provides a list of row names for split; removing that column allowed pivot.wider to operate. Thanks a ton.